# CMFCListCtrl- LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL

Tags: mfc

In a MFC dialog based application I am using CMFClistCtrl with LVS_OWNERDATA style. I am using LVSICF_NOSCROLL flag for SetItemCountEx().

I saw one more flag LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL.

when to use this flag LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL?

I saw the msdn explanation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/lvm-setitemcount, but I could not understand properly.

We can do many operation like adding, deleting, editing, sorting etc in list control so at what scenario I have to use this flag?

Please anyone help me

Comment: My understanding is this: Say your list control contains 10 items and shows 10 items per page. When you call `SetItemCountEx(20, LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL)` it will not refresh the view, because the additional 10 items will be outside of the view. So unless the *data* shown by the list control also has changed, I would always use this flag to prevent unnecessary flickering.

Comment: @zett42, thank you for the reply.Your comment helped me to understand when to use LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL.